# MySQL INSERT IGNORE without TimeStamp

Tags: mysql, constraints

Good evening, I have one table, with a timestamp column, then I have a tool to insert into this table N registries. To avoid duplicate information in this table, I've used `INSERT IGNORE`, but of course as you can imagine with the timestamp attribute always the new row is different. I cannot make a previous search and check the result set in my code, because I'm adding all the queries into a statement batch, that's why I'm using INSERT IGNORE.
So the question would be, it is possible avoid the timestamp column when I'm making a compare between the new row and all the previous already inserted? the first time that used the tool?

Regards!.

Comment: create a unique key on the fields you don't want duplicated, and exclude the timestamp field from that key.

Comment: @Marc B You should make that the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a unique key on the fields you don't want duplicated, and exclude the timestamp field from that key.

Comment: I just hope that this key would not be create on too many column if that is the situation. Any workaround in this case?

Comment: Not really. Either check ahead of time, or use the key to make mysql check for you. Maybe a trigger could do the check for you, but then you'd still be checking for each row.